# Extract field list from reStructuredText

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docutils

Say I have the following reST input:

```
Some text ...

:foo: bar

Some text ...
```

What I would like to end up with is a dict like this:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

I tried to use this:

```
tree = docutils.core.publish_parts(text)
```

It does parse the field list, but I end up with some pseudo XML in `tree["whole"]?`:

```
<document source="<string>">
    <docinfo>
        <field>
            <field_name>
                foo
            <field_body>
                <paragraph>
                    bar
```

Since the `tree` dict does not contain any other useful information and that is just a string, I am not sure how to parse the field list out of the reST document. How would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use something like the following code. Rather than using the `publish_parts` method I have used [`publish_doctree`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/publisher.html), to get the pseudo-XML representation of your document. I have then converted to an XML DOM in order to extract all the `field` elements. Then I get the first `field_name` and `field_body` elements of each `field` element.

```
from docutils.core import publish_doctree

source = """Some text ...

:foo: bar

Some text ...
"""

# Parse reStructuredText input, returning the Docutils doctree as
# an `xml.dom.minidom.Document` instance.
doctree = publish_doctree(source).asdom()

# Get all field lists in the document.
fields = doctree.getElementsByTagName('field')

d = {}

for field in fields:
    # I am assuming that `getElementsByTagName` only returns one element.
    field_name = field.getElementsByTagName('field_name')[0]
    field_body = field.getElementsByTagName('field_body')[0]

    d[field_name.firstChild.nodeValue] = \
        " ".join(c.firstChild.nodeValue for c in field_body.childNodes)

print d # Prints {u'foo': u'bar'}
```

The [xml.dom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) module isn't the easiest to work with (why do I need to use `.firstChild.nodeValue` rather than just `.nodeValue` for example), so you may wish to use the [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module, which I find a lot easier to work with. If you use lxml you can also use XPATH notation to find all of the `field`, `field_name` and `field_body` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative solution that I find to be less of a burden, but maybe more brittle. After reviewing the implementation of the node class https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/docutils/docutils/nodes.py you will see that it supports a walk method that can be used to pull out the wanted data without having to create two different xml representations of your data. Here is what I am using now, in my protoype code:

https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/gcc-introspector/blob/master/peewee_adaptor.py#L33

```
from docutils.core import publish_doctree
import docutils.nodes
```

and then

```
def walk_docstring(prop):
    doc = prop.__doc__
    doctree = publish_doctree(doc)
    class Walker:
        def __init__(self, doc):
            self.document = doc
            self.fields = {}
        def dispatch_visit(self,x):
            if isinstance(x, docutils.nodes.field):
                field_name = x.children[0].rawsource
                field_value = x.children[1].rawsource
                self.fields[field_name]=field_value
    w = Walker(doctree)
    doctree.walk(w)
    # the collected fields I wanted
    pprint.pprint(w.fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) implementation:

```
from docutils.core import publish_doctree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring

source = """Some text ...

:foo: bar

Some text ...
"""


def gen_fields(source):
    dom = publish_doctree(source).asdom()
    tree = fromstring(dom.toxml())

    for field in tree.iter(tag='field'):
        name = next(field.iter(tag='field_name'))
        body = next(field.iter(tag='field_body'))
        yield {name.text: ''.join(body.itertext())}
```

Usage

```
>>> next(gen_fields(source))
{'foo': 'bar'}
```