# Turn fields in reStructuredText into html

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docutils

So I've got a reStructuredText document which includes fields:

```
:param foo: set this to do magic
```

and I want to turn the rST into html, with special treatment of `param` (and other) fields.

Turning rST into html can be done with `docutils.core.publish_parts` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766609/extract-field-list-from-restructuredtext/10782270#10782270), but obviously without control of how fields are output.  Or I can use `docutils.core.publish_doctree` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766609/extract-field-list-from-restructuredtext) to get the pseudo-XML, and presumably (fairly tediously) modify that, but I don't see how I can control how this is translated to html.

I can see there's a `HTMLTranslator` class in `docutils.writers.html4css1.__init__.py`, but I surely can't have to modify this just to control how fields are output? I'm hoping there's some sort of template system somewhere which controls how XML is translated to html ...

Comment: Converting the document tree Python object to HTML can be done with [publish_from_doctree()](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/api/publisher.html#publish-from-doctree).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this and let me know if this help u out

[ReStructuredText (reST)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ReStructuredText)

Comment: Well it's a minimal example of deriving from HTMLTranslator which would be OK if I had to go down this route, but doing this and setting up visit_field methods still seems way too complicated given fields are listed as an extensibility mechanism in the docutils docs.

Comment: sorry that I couldn't come up with much more, reST is highly undocumented it seems